Which battles were the swords of the initial structure of the Iron Throne taken from?
In A Song of Ice and Fire, the Iron Throne is depicted as composed of melted down swords of the armies that Aegon the Conqueror defeated. The author has stated that this is one of the closest depictions of the throne.
Which battles were these swords taken from? Was there an effort to collect them as he went?
Insight into any of the details (other than "Balerion melted them") of the throne's construction are welcomed.

You're asking three different questions here, and while they're somewhat related, we generally prefer each question to focus on one specific query. As such, there is possibility that users of this site will vote to close this question on the grounds of it being insufficiently focused, unless you edit it to make it more focused. You have the option of posting one or two of these three questions in a separate post if you like.

I believed the background required to answer the primary question would yield the answer for the others. Is it not common to have followup questions as a means of promoting a nuanced discussion in the answer? Happy to make a post on meta if that's not the case

After a certain point, any new swords "acquired" could just be stuck in any-old-where.

Sure, but the primary structure of the throne had to be planned in some way; after all, ferrying all that steel from distant battlefields to be melted into a throne would be a less obvious choice than, say, using it to equip your own armies. Hence the question!

The Field of Fire, largely
During his conquest, Aegon I faced some resistance. Most notably, from the King of the Reach (House Gardener) and the King of The Rock (House Casterly). Who raised a sizeable army and met Aegon in the fields as Aegon approaced.
This culminated in the decimation of much those armies of those kings by Aegon and his sister-queens (Visenya and Rhaenys) with their dragons (Balerion "The Black Dread", Vhagar and Meraxes), in a battle known as the Field of Fire.
After a short skirmish where the kings of the Reach and Rock were starting to gain the upperhand, Aegon and his sister-queens "took to the air", and started raining fire onto the soldiers.

It was the only time that Vhagar, Meraxes, and Balerion were all unleashed at once. The singers called it the Field of Fire. -A Game of Thrones, Chapter 13, Tyrion II

The kings immediately surrendered.
After the battle, it is said that the swords of the fallen soldiers were gathered and sent back to Aegon's stronghold, Aegonfort, to be melted down and make part of what we now know as the Iron Throne.
This is confirmed in:

A Game of Thrones
The World of Ice and Fire
A Knight of the Seven Kingdoms (Dunk and Egg novellas)

It is noted that the swords were ferried down the Blackwater Rush.
Looted/Collected
It is also noted that more swords were collected and added to the Throne as Aegon's conquest continued and some swords were

wrenched from the hands of the dying -Iron Throne - ASoIaF Wiki

Symbolic Significance of the Iron Throne
You'll note that the Iron Throne is an eternal representation of Aegon's Conquest.
Sure, the swords could have been recycled, or even sent back to their original lands for re-use. But when you look at what the Iron Throne signifies - the complete conquer of the lands, rulers and people of Westeros - you will see that henceforth, the Throne acts as a reminder to all those who are forced before it to swear/continue their fealty to the Targaryens.
Design First
We are unsure who designed the Throne, or came up with the idea to melt the swords and incorporate them into it.
